# Angular 2 Pass parameter variable to a validator function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom validator that needs to have access to a local components' variable. In my component I have a variable boolean that gets changed as user interacts with a form

```
export class MyForm implements OnInit{
  public localBool : boolean;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder)
  ngOnInit(){
     this.form = this.fb.group({
         field : ['', [CustomValidator.validateIfRequired(this.localBool)]]
     })
  }

}


export CustomValidator {
    static validateIfRequired(condition:boolean){
          console.log(condition);
          ....
    }

}
```

I get undefined When I use it like so

```
CustomValidator.validateIfRequired(this.localBool)
```

But I get true when i use it like so

```
CustomValidator.validateIfRequired(true)
```

How can I pass or evaluate the local variable? +1 for a brief explanation of how Angular evaluates the parameter and why I get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using validators like this

```
import {Control} from "@angular/common";

interface ValidationResult {
    [key: string]: boolean;
}

export function emailFormat(control: Control): ValidationResult {
    var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;

    if (control.value != "" && (control.value.length <= 5 || !EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value))) {
        return {"incorrectMailFormat": true};
    }
    return null;
}

export class LoginPage {
    public loginForm: ControlGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.loginForm = fb.group({
            'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, emailFormat])],
            'password': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])]
        });
    }
}
```